# Clojure : Get the values from each vector of vectors and pass that as an argument to the other function

Tags: vector, clojure

I want to take the values from vector of vectors and want to pass that values as argument to another function. I want to call the other function as many vectors I have in the collection of vectors of vector.

For eg :

This is demo code that will explain what I am trying

```
    (defn demo
            [arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5]
            (println "====== in Demo=======")
            (println arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5)
    )

    (def vv [["item1" "item2" "item3" 4] ["item5" "item6" "item7" 80.0] .....])
```

I want a function that can iterate through vv and take value of each v and pass it as an argument to **demo**

```
    (def somefun 
    iterate [i vv] demo (get v 0) (get v 1) (get v 2) (get v 3))
```

;; this should repeat for all the vectors in vv

Comment: Try to frame the problem so that the work of the functions is expressed in their *return value*, which can be as complex as you like. Don't print results - return them. You will then find that Clojure has lots of higher-order functions that can express most of the things you would want from a vector of vectors.

Comment: thank you @Thumbnail I have used **println** in my above statement, just for understanding. I want to use that arguments in my own way .

Comment: `(doseq [v vv] (apply demo v))`  Assuming the number of arguments expected by demo is the same as the length of `v`, which is not the case in your example vectors.

Comment: @jas Thanks alot !  It did work while passing the arguments, but there is one problem with **doseq** I suppose. It does not return any thing right ?
Suppose I am getting some value from **Demo** function. Then can I evaluate here as , 

        `(and (doseq [v vv] (apply demo v))`

for eg :
Suppose for one set of arguments the demo function is sending _true_ , for next it sends me _false_ and so on ...
so here I would get `(and (true false true true false .... .. .. ))`

doseq will always return **nill**

Comment: @jas Hey I guess I can use **for** instead of **doseq**  with apply, it will also return me the values received from the **Demo** function;

`(for [v vv] apply demo v)`

Answer (score 0):

Since iteration in functional languages often means `map`, I would do it like this:

```
(defn somefun [vv]
    (map (partial apply demo) vv)
```

The map iterates over all vectors. The `partial` function appends each `v` to the mapping function. In the end you call `(apply demo v)` for every `v` in `vv`.

The `apply` takes the vector and turns its elements into arguments for `demo`.